# Is it available if Kafka Sink consume multiple sink into multiple table with standalone configuration?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have read that an Kafka connect source can receive a multiple topics from a database (a topic represent one table). I have PostgreSQL database with many table, and one Kafka source are satisfied enough for this time. But is it available if I declare only single JDBC Kafka sink to consume all the topics into topic-based destination table, for example all tables from PostgreSQL into single MS SQL Server Database? It is time-cost, for example if I have 200 Tables from one database and must make 200 sinks connection for each tables, although I only need to declare the source once.

Comment: I don't really understand what you try to achieve. You need a way to push tables from: Postgresql--->KAFKA--->MS SQL ?

Comment: yes, i want to migrate one postgresql db into one MSSQL database using kafka connectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Debezium to snapshot one database and all tables to send them over Kafka and dump to any other sink connector (including MSSQL), yes

How many connectors you need to run or how many tables on the destination you'll create are ultimately up to your own configurations

And standalone doesn't matter, but distributed mode is preferred anyway, even if you are only using one machine

Comment: i have use debezium in my source, but still think about the structure. I want to use only one standalone workers and only one sink for one database. Is it possible to do with this config?

Comment: Yes, but can you please explain why you're convinced that "standalone" mode is better than distributed?

Comment: i still have experienced using the standalone one... still try to find any possibilities to find the best practice for this case. At this point, after read this one from Robin Moffatt in DEV.io [link] (https://dev.to/rmoff/should-you-run-kafka-connect-in-distributed-or-standalone-mode-15gn),  based from my case and this is development db that being the source, i will try the standalone one as base path.

Comment: I don't mean that standalone is better, but if the best case are the distributed one, i will take consideration about it. but the main case if is it available to deploy only one kafka jdbc sink to dump all database based from every topics that consume from source db.

Comment: The sink config requires you to only list one table but there's `topics.regex` allows you to consume all topics

Comment: Great thanks. i will try this and if there's problem with performance measurement, i will try to use distributed

Comment: They both call the exact same methods internally. Distributed mode stores data back in a topic for fault tolerance rather than in a file on disk. That's one why it's recommended. The other is that you just install it on more machines, and it scales much quicker